# send private message facebook sdk android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

I try to find solution for send message in facebook for another user use sdk android. I look for open dialog, but it's not possible use sdk + send message i think, that is not possible too. 
all answer in stack not update longtime. 
maybe anyone find the solutions for that question. 
maybe i need to look for send message via browser use post???
or use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference.
anyone use that api sender?

yes i find https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog
but that not func for send message..

thanks for you time.

Comment: There is no way to send private messages from one user to another via API. The Send dialog, that lets a user send a link to a friend, is the most you can get.

Comment: send dialog i can use just for web-platform and not for android. For android o find "MessageDialog.show(activityOrFragment, content);" but not parameter no another info

Comment: Then use MessageDialog

Answer (score 1):

So... i spend 2 day for find best solutions.
for quick solutions you must use code like this:

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(this);
    messageDialog.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.e("myLogs", "send success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("myLogs", "send cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e("myLogs", "send error");
        }
    });

    if (MessageDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html");


        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("....")
                .setContentDescription("asd")
                .setContentUrl(uri)
        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"))
        .build();

        messageDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

but this work just with "messenger"!!!
and i think for create web part and create webhook for send request from android to webplatform and on this platform use dialog message for send a friend. But i not release this. 
If anyone wanna try 2nd methode and it's will be done good result. please write in this place.

good coding

Comment: First I tried to share to messenger via `ShareToMessengerParams` and `MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger` but I realized that this way of sharing only allows to share drawables from your device, since the image you are sharing must come from your device. So I tried your code snippet but sadly when I hit the "SEND" Button the Messenger Dialog just opens for a second or two and the closes immediately, so I can't share the content via Messenger. Do you maybe know what could cause this problem?

Comment: salut, sorry for big delay, yes i know where is you problems, paste you parameters, which you use in ShareLinkContent.   (3 day ago i restart work with facebook)